# How can I recover a broken Git workspace?

Tags: git, bash, github, atlassian-sourcetree, git-status

My configuration is with Win10, latest Git 2.10 and I work with GitHUB using SourceTree.
For SourceTree, it uses the Git version of my system (not the embedded one).

Apparently a couple of files of 2Mb size (yes I double checked it), pop-up a warning  inside sourceTree when trying to stage the files, asking for lfs connection and configuration. I followed up the lfs set up (from within sourceTree).
At this point, trying to get the git status reports this error.

```
git-lfs clean -- 'path/AMyimageI.png': git-lfs: command not found

error: external filter git-lfs clean -- %f failed -1

error: external filter git-lfs clean -- %f failed
fatal: path/AMyimageI.png: clean filter 'lfs' failed
```

Which then took me to install the git lfs from [here](https://git-lfs.github.com/), followed by the "git lfs install".
Another try to "**git status**" (from pure Git bash) only hangs and does nothing.

After uninstalling git-lfs and restarting SourceTree I get this warning
[image: SourceTreeWarning]

and again the previous error is reported.

Some of my files are staged already, some not. I don't want to reset to my last commit and get my work lost. What are the possible solutions to recover git from this error?

I tried just letting my partial commit go, from the Git bash, again no response.

Appreciate your help.

Cheers.

Comment: Should you just remove all the lines in the `.gitattributes` file containing `filter=lfs`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clicking the NO, in the SourceTree pop up window fixed the problem.
Apparently a conflict happens locally installing the git lfs and the one that's been used in our GitHUB.

I did have to uninstall git lfs also and all works.
Thank you.